# Impedance of a blowing instrument

Tags: python, acoustics

I'm trying to reproduce the model described in this paper https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/file/index/docid/683477/filename/clarinette-logique-8.pdf.

Here is a method that returns the transfer matrix for a cylinder of radius a and length L.

```
# density of air
rho = 1.2250

# viscosity of air
eta = 18.5

# transfer matrix for a cylinder
def Tcyl(a, L):
    rv = a * math.sqrt(rho*omega/eta)
    Z0 = (rho * constants.c) / (constants.pi * a**2)
    Zc = Z0 * complex(1 + 0.369/rv, -(0.369/rv + 1.149/rv**2))
    gamma = k * complex(1.045/rv + 1.080/rv**2, 1 + 1.045/rv)
    return
       np.matrix([[cmath.cosh(gamma*L),Zc*cmath.sinh(gamma*L)],
       [(1.0/Zc)*cmath.sinh(gamma*L),cmath.cosh(gamma*L)]], dtype=complex)
```

The input impedance is calculated for different frequencies as follow.

```
for f in range(1,4000):
    
    # angular frequency
    omega = 2*constants.pi*f

    # wave number
    k = omega/constants.c

    # transfer matrix for a cylinder of radius 7.5mm and length 100mm
    T = Tcyl(7.5, 100.0)

    # radiation impedance
    Zr = complex(0,0)

    # [P,U] vector (pression and velocity)
    T = np.dot(T,np.matrix([[Zr],[complex(1,0)]], dtype=complex))

    # input impedance (Z = P/U)
    Z = T.item(0)/T.item(1)
```

The playing frequency satisfy the equation Im[Z]=0. When plotting the imaginary part of Z I get the following figure : [wrong impedance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkewU.png)

This is clearly wrong as the expected output should be something like this : [correct impedance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4BsC.gif)

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: (1) Show in the question the code how you plot this. (2) If variables "omega" and "k" are used in "Tcyl" they should also be parameters of the function.

Comment: You are right omega and k should be parameters of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
    Z0 = (rho * constants.c) / (constants.pi * a**2)
```

The impedance of a clarinet depends on the speed of SOUND, not the speed of LIGHT.  Replace `constants.c` with `343` and your results will be closer.  I'm still not sure it's quite right, but closer.

As a clarinetist, I try to make people think my fingers move as fast as light, but it ain't so.

Comment: Haha this is so embarrassing. It works perfectly now ! Thank you !!!

Comment: Some other corrections : air viscosity must be 0.0000181, radius and length must be expressed in meters.